# How to locate a specific button inside a class. The button might share classname with other button outside this class

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

This is the button with classname action. How can I point to only this button inside this snackbar class. I need the xpath.

```
<div class="snackbar-container  snackbar-pos bottom-center" style="width: 475px; background: rgb(50, 50, 50); opacity: 1;" xpath="1">
   <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1em;">Show similar patients for  Jerry Rocker</p>
   <button class="action" style="color: rgb(76, 175, 80);">SHOW</button>
</div>
```

Tried this.
WebElement

```
snackbarButton=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'action') and contains(@class,'snackbar-pos']"));
```

---

```
    <div class="snackbar-container  snackbar-pos bottom-center" style="width: 475px; background: rgb(50, 50, 50); opacity: 1;" xpath="1">
       <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1em;">Show similar patients for  Jerry Rocker</p>
       <button class="action" style="color: rgb(76, 175, 80);">SHOW</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. This question is really need an example of html that you want to find. Please read [the article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about a minimal, reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you intent to click on the button with text as **SHOW** associated with the element with text as **Show similar patients for  Jerry Rocker** and to achieve that you to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath1`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[text()='Show similar patients for  Jerry Rocker']//following::button[1]"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath2`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[text()='Show similar patients for  Jerry Rocker']//following::button[@class='action' and text()='SHOW']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the button which is a child of [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) tag which [`class` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) contains `snackbar-pos` you could go for the following expression:

```
//div[contains(@class,'snackbar-pos')]/button
```

Demo:

[image]

However it might make more sense to stick to this [`xpath` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp):

```
//div[@xpath='1']/button
```

Or even this `Jerry Rocker` text:

```
//p[contains(text(),'Jerry Rocker')]/following-sibling::button
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below given xpath.

```
//div[@class='snackbar-container  snackbar-pos bottom-center']//child::p//following-sibling::button[@class='action']
```

Hope this will help.